# ACS doesn't process SAML response in a sub-application

Tags: .net, forms-authentication, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm struggling to find the cause of this behavior. I have a simple MVC application with the SustainSys package configured. I've tried configuring it for both our internal SecureAuth server and also the https://stubidp.sustainsys.com test server.

It all works on localhost and when it's the root application of our internal IIS server.

When I place it in an IIS sub-application folder, it redirects to the sso server login, comes back to the ~/Saml2/Acs route with the authentication info (I see it in fiddler2), but the Acs doesn't seem to process it at that point and I remain unauthenticated and therefore it heads back to the login page and I start looping.

I'm aware of sub-app web.config inheritance, so I've even removed the web.config from the root so nothing is conflicting with the one in the sub-app. I've played with the returnURL parameter to no effect (with or without sudirectory included).

The applications in IIS (root and sub-app) are configured the same for authentication.

I'm running out of ideas to test. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://apps.xxxxx.com" returnUrl="https://apps.xxxxx.com/yyyyy">
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="https://sso.xxxxx.com/SecureAuthXX" signOnUrl="https://sso.xxxxx.com/SecureAuthXX" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/SecureAuth03VM.xxxxx.com.cer" />
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <federations>
        <add metadataLocation="https://apps.xxxxx.com/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
    </federations>
</sustainsys.saml2>
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" name="CookieAuth" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: What Sustainsys package are you using? Sustains.Saml2.Mvc? Or Owin? Or the HttpModule?

Comment: @AndersAbel Sustains.Saml2.Mvc. I feel like it's an issue with the audience, but I can't confirm it.

Comment: @AndersAbel Update, I've now deployed the MVC sample site from SustainSys to the sub-application directory and it doesn't work in that scenario either. I can see the SAML response coming back from stubidp.sustainsys.com using a SAML panel in the Chrome debugger and it contains the successful assertion coming back with "JohnDoe" for the name, but the Acs is ignoring it and not signing in. I'm fiddling entityID and returnUrl values but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and I wanted to post what fixed it as maybe it might help someone else one day.

The issue was not with the SAML response or the Sustainsys library, but rather an attribute missing the from the web.config. After adding "path='/'" to the cookiehandler element in the federation configuration (see below), it begin persisting the authorization state in the System.Security.Principal and now works perfectly in the root application as well as all sub-applications.

```
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" name="FedAuth" path="/" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps where <edit>I thought</edit> this could go wrong:

1. The Acs Url in the genereated AuthnRequest is incorrect. Please check the displayed XML content on the StubIdp to see if it correctly reflects the sub-application directory. If not, this is a bug/missing feature in the Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc package.
2. The application does not correctly invoke the MVC controller embedded in the Sustainsys.Mvc package when deployed to a sub directory. You can test this by hitting http://yoursite.com/SubDir/Saml2 - if it works it should return the metadata XML. If this is the case, you need to review the route configuration in your application to ensure that the path is correctly routed to the controller in the MVC package.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but neither has solved the issue. The Acs URL is correct, and also the mvc routing is correctly invoking the Acs controller property which I can see happening in fiddler. Hitting the main Saml2 route does indeed return the metadata. I think I'm going to try to add the Sustainsys source to my project so I can step into the code that's called in the Acs route and hopefully be enlightened.